# Asymptomatic infections in the Pfizer/BioNTech approval study of Covid-19 vaccine

Tags: covid-19, asymptomatic

The usual criticism of the [Pfizer / BioNTech approval study](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/nejmoa2034577) for their mRNA Covid-19 Vaccine was that asymptomatic infections could not be detected.

But according to the [protocol](https://www.nejm.org/doi/suppl/10.1056/NEJMoa2034577/suppl_file/nejmoa2034577_protocol.pdf), page 65, regular visits are scheduled, though with long intervals, like 6 or 12 months.

As far as I understand the study:

- no PCR testing was done at the scheduled visits on asymptomatic patients
- instead, blood samples were taken for immunogenicity testing (testing for non-vaccine antibodies)

Now to quote from the study:

> These data do not address whether vaccination prevents asymptomatic infection; a serologic end point that can detect a history of infection regardless of whether symptoms were present (SARS-CoV-2 N-binding antibody) will be reported later.

This is the important part. Has this data been reported by now? If so, where?